# Access Manufacturer specific settings ex. Samsung Find My Device

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-mobile, android-settings

I am reading the Android developers reference and the classes listed there seem straightforward.
Although there are some settings on some phones specific to the manufacturer.

For example, under Biometrics & Security settings , Samsung lists some extra settings like "Find my device" , "Samsung Pass" etc....

How can i access those settings API?

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't access those. There is no requirement for Samsung to make any of that available to third-party developers. If there is a supported path for it, it would involve some Samsung-specific SDK, so you might check their developer site.